# How to take elements from query 1 which are not in query 2 in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query in Oracle SQL:

```
query1
select ID from table1

query2
select ID from table2
UNION 
select ID from table3
```

I would like to take all IDs from query 1 but remove those from query 1 which are in query 2, so for example:

results of query1

```
1, 2, 3
```

results of query2:

```
3, 4, 5
```

My expected result would be:

```
1 , 2  -- because they are in query 1 but not in query2.
```

How can I do that ? Be aware that query 2 is created by using UNION

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to take all IDs from query 1 but remove those from query 1 which are in query 2, so for example:

You can use `minus`:

```
select ID from table1
minus
(select ID from table2
 union 
 select ID from table3
)
```

If performance is an issue, you might also compare the above to:

```
select t1.id
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id) and
      not exists (select 1 from table3 t3 where t3.id = t1.id);
```

These do not incur overhead for removing duplicates, so they might be faster.

Comment: Gordon and is it possible so as to query2 be the first one ? query2 minus query1 ? But still I want to remove elements from query1 which are in query2 ?

Comment: @Matop . . . This answers the question that you asked.  However, it should be easy to modify for other combinations of keeping and getting-rid-of.